# how to hide child of configurable product in Category page magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, category, configurable-product

I want to display **configrable product** without **child product** in **Category page** and when i access the product page of the configurable product i get the child according to my choice

So how to do that please and thanks in advance

Comment: Set the visibility "Not Visible Individual" for every child product.

Comment: can i get them in  configurable product page if i set that ??

Comment: Yes, you can get the child products on product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go To the Child Product > Edit > Visiblity > Not Visible Individual

Set the visibility **Not Visible Individual** for every child product